# Rebuilt Computer, back to Startup Repair after 1 day

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot

I have an Acer Nitro Windows 10 PC, around 3 years old.

Last week we were using the computer fine. Turned off. Turned back on, it went to Windows Startup Repair. No options did anything.

I bought a new copy of Windows 10 and a new hard drive.

Yesterday I fitted the new hard drive and loaded up Windows 10, all good. Copied back all programs and files, working machine again! Used the computer fine for a few hours. Turned off.

Turning on this morning, back to Startup Repair again?!?!

Again, all options to repair do nothing.

I put the Windows 10 media in again, hoping to reinstall/repair Windows again, but when I got to the screen where you select install location, this is what I see - it shows no drives?!

[image]

I turned off, unplugged mains, reseated the hard drive SATA cables, Still the same.

I am hugely confused about what to do next. How can this happen after 1 day of a new install?

Does this now point to a Motherboard fault?

I also wonder if having the computer unpowered for the 3 days I was waiting for the new hard drive to arrive made a difference?

Computer currently sitting unplugged, but I am out of ideas as to what to do next or how to solve this.

EDIT:

Tried swapping cables. No difference.

Took an old hard drive, formatted it, put it in the computer. Computer started up, found the drive, re-installed Windows 10 again. Installation went through and computer started up into Windows.

Turned computer off. Back on again. Same result. Starting automatic repair. No options work.

So computer will work with a blank drive, and will allow installation of Windows to a blank drive, and will work as long as it is not turned off!

If turned off, it won't restart, but will always go into startup repair.

Comment: Do you keep plugging it into the same SATA port on the motherboard? You could try a different SATA port, otherwise it sounds like the SATA controller has gone bad, which means you would need to replace your motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

First test.

Change the SATA cable & the mobo socket you route to. Make sure there are absolutely no kinks or bends in the cable & absolutely no strain on either plug/socket. Move the drive & rest it on something if you have to, to get everything in a nice straight line, leave the side off.
Use some contact cleaner if you have some or carefully push/pull the plugs a dozen times to shine up the contacts (power off of course).

Test again.

The number of times random read/write/data loss/missing drive issues have turned out to be a dodgy cable or dodgy connection, it's now literally my first test.